# GWT Autobean Bean is null

Tags: java, gwt, autobean

Please help me, what I do wrong

**InfraNameModel**

```
public interface InfraNameModel {
    String getInfraName();

    void setInfraName(String infraName);
}
```

**InfraNameModelImpl**

```
public class InfraNameModelImpl implements InfraNameModel {
    private String infraName;

    @Override
    public String getInfraName() {
        return infraName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInfraName(String infraName) {
        this.infraName = infraName;
    }
}
```

**InfraNameModelList**

```
public interface InfraNameModelList<T extends InfraNameModel> {

    public List<T> getInfraNameModelList();

    public void setInfraNameModelList(List<T> infraNameModel);
}
```

**InfraNameModelListImpl**

```
public class InfraNameModelListImpl implements InfraNameModelList<InfraNameModel> {
    private List<InfraNameModel> infraNameModelList;

    @Override
    public List<InfraNameModel> getInfraNameModelList() {
        return infraNameModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInfraNameModelList(List<InfraNameModel> infraNameModelList) {
        this.infraNameModelList = infraNameModelList;
    }
}
```

**IBeanFactory**

```
public interface IBeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    IBeanFactory INSTANCE = GWT.create(IBeanFactory.class);

    AutoBean<InfraNameModel> infraNameModel();

    AutoBean<InfraNameModelList> infraNameModelList();
}
```

...

```
            InfraNameModelList infraNameModelList = beanFactory.deserializeFromJson(" [{\"infraName\":\"TEST1\"},{\"infraName\":\"TEST2\"}}");
            if (infraNameModelList == null)
                logger.info("infraNameModelList=== null");
            else
                logger.info("infraNameModelList not null " + infraNameModelList);
            List<InfraNameModelImpl> infraNameModel = infraNameModelList.getInfraNameModelList();
            if (infraNameModel == null)
                logger.info("infraNameModel=== null");
            else
                logger.info("infraNameModel=== not null " + infraNameModel);
            InfraNameModelImpl infraNameModelImpl = infraNameModel.get(0);
            if (infraNameModel == null)
                logger.info("infraNameModelImpl=== null");
            else
                logger.info("infraNameModelImpl=== not null " + infraNameModelImpl);
            logger.info("===" + infraNameModelImpl.getInfraName());
```

So I have such error
In this line

**ConsoleLogger.java:32 infraNameModel=== null**

Why infraNameModel is null??? =(

```
===SUCCESS
ConsoleLogger.java:32 ===[{"infraName":"TEST1"},{"infraName":"TEST2"}]
ConsoleLogger.java:32 infraNameModelList not null by.client.models.infraNameModel.InfraNameModelListAutoBean$2@36
ConsoleLogger.java:32 infraNameModel=== null
ConsoleLogger.java:32 (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'get_18_g$' of null
H3f_g$ @ ConsoleLogger.java:32
eAf_g$ @ SimpleConsoleLogHandler.java:36
szf_g$ @ Logger.java:312
rzf_g$ @ Logger.java:302
Pzf_g$ @ Logger.java:236
rad_g$ @ LogConfiguration.java:169
lab_g$ @ Impl.java:186
$9_g$ @ Impl.java:293
(anonymous) @ Impl.java:77
ConsoleLogger.java:55 Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'get_18_g$' of null
ConsoleLogger.java:32 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_18_g$' of null
    at uHg_g$.D$g_g$ [as onSuccess_8_g$] (Configuration.java:71)
    at uHg_g$.xHg_g$ [as onSuccess_1_g$] (Configuration.java:55)
    at S9f_g$.Ny_g$ [as onResponseReceived_0_g$] (AbstractRequestCallback.java:94)
    at ZLc_g$.aMc_g$ [as fireOnResponseReceived_0_g$] (Request.java:250)
    at hNc_g$.iNc_g$ [as onReadyStateChange_0_g$] (RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (XMLHttpRequest.java:329)
    at X9_g$ (Impl.java:239)
    at $9_g$ (Impl.java:291)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (Impl.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why infraNameModel is null??? =(

Because an Array does not have an `infraNameModelList` property.

You'd have to wrap the JSON array into an object with such a property to make it match your AutoBean model.

Comment: I just read you answer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/8Ts07mG0Ci8 4 years ago.
Can you describe in more detail???

Comment: [{\"infraName\":\"TEST1\"},{\"infraName\":\"TEST2\"}] ............... Need I wrap this JSON in {
 "results" : [{
   "infraName" : "TEST1"
  }, {
   "infraName" : "TEST2"
  }
 ]
}
?