# GWT Autobean List for different objects

Tags: java, gwt, autobean

In addon my question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136109/gwt-autobean-bean-is-null/42137661#42137661)

**My JSON**

```
{
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "count" : 1,
    "type" : "InfraNameModel",
    "results" : [{
            "infraName" : "TEST1"
        }
    ]
}
```

**IBeanFactory**

```
public interface IBeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    IBeanFactory INSTANCE = GWT.create(IBeanFactory.class);
    AutoBean<InfraNameModel> infraName();
    AutoBean<InfraNameListModel> results();
}
```

**InfraNameListModel**

```
public interface InfraNameListModel {
    List<InfraNameModel> getResults();    
    void setResults(List<InfraNameModel> infraNameModel);
}
```

**InfraNameListModelImpl**

```
public class InfraNameListModelImpl implements InfraNameListModel {  
    private List<InfraNameModel> results;    
    @Override
    public List<InfraNameModel> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void setResults(List<InfraNameModel> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

**InfraNameModel**

```
public interface InfraNameModel {
    String getInfraName();   
    void setInfraName(String infraName);
}
```

**InfraNameModelImpl**

```
public class InfraNameModelImpl implements InfraNameModel {
    private String infraName;
    @Override
    public String getInfraName() {
        return infraName;
    }
    @Override
    public void setInfraName(String infraName) {
        this.infraName = infraName;
    }
}
```

How I use

```
            InfraNameListModel infraNameListModel = beanFactory.deserializeFromJson(jsonParser.getResultsJSON());
            logger.info(infraNameListModel.toString());
            List<InfraNameModel> infraNameModelList = infraNameListModel. getResults();
            logger.info(infraNameModelList.toString());
            InfraNameModel infraNameModelImpl = infraNameModelList.get(0);
            logger.info(infraNameModelImpl.toString());
```

All work fine. But I have a questuion.

In the "Results" can come different types of beans.How to make a generic List for all types?

I try so

```
public interface ResultsModel<T> {
    List<T> getResults();
    void setResults(List<T> infraNameModel);
}
```

**InfraNameResultsModelImpl**

```
public class InfraNameResultsModelImpl implements ResultsModel<InfraNameModel> {
    private List<InfraNameModel> results;
    @Override
    public List getResults() {
        return results;
    }
    @Override
    public void setResults(List infraNameModel) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

But error = (

Is it possible to implement a common List  for all types of results?

```
            ResultsModel<InfraNameModel> resultsModel = beanFactory.deserializeFromJson(ResultsModel.class,jsonParser.getResultsJSON());
            logger.info(resultsModel.toString());
            List<InfraNameModel> infraNameModelList = resultsModel. getResults();
            logger.info(infraNameModelList.toString());
            InfraNameModel infraNameModelImpl = infraNameModelList.get(0);
            logger.info(infraNameModelImpl.toString());
```

Comment: Autobeans don't support arbitrary subtypes, but you can get close by re-decoding Splittable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234601/parsing-json-objects-of-unknown-type-with-autobean-on-gwt for an idea. If that doesn't help, update the question with details, and I'll give it a shot?

Comment: I can not decide this problem= (((